# Android default selector

Tags: android, selector, android-linearlayout

In my app I have inflated a ListView with this row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rootrow_layout" android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/containerHistory" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                <TextView android:textSize="16sp" android:gravity="left"
                    android:padding="5dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:text="Unknown location " android:id="@+id/historyLocation"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000"></TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout03"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                <TextView android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:gravity="left" android:padding="5dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:text="Complete" android:typeface="serif" android:id="@+id/historyDate"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000"></TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout04"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dip" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/check" android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></CheckBox>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now I would add an event (OnClickListener) on my root layout. I can get the event but I can't see the default selector (for example I have Galaxy S2 and on list click I have a blue background).

Can I set the default selector on LinearLayout click event?

I attach a screenshot for my default selector on Galaxy S2.
[image: Galaxy S2 ListView item selector]

---

Sorry, I've tried solution:

@android:drawable/list_selector_background

Comment: try to use the listview's `setOnItemClickListener` instead of using a clicklistener for each view

Comment: I've tried but for my app I can't do it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Modify your root LinearLayout to become like this (NOTICE THE LAST LINE!)

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rootrow_layout"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background">
```

Answer (score 3):

add this code in your xml list view.

```
android:listSelector="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
```